# How to run Windows Phone emulator in VMware

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, vmware

I'm trying to make a simple Windows Phone application on a Macbook Pro. So I'm running Visual Studio in Windows 7 inside of VMware Fusion.

When I try to run the phone emulator, this is what I get.

[image]

I looked for settings that I could modify to the virtual machine settings but didn't find any.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this technique will probably not work for you. I had the same issue when I was on my PC and wanted to create iPhone applications. VMWare (and other Virtual Machines) are not fully gfx enabled. You need to check the box that says "Accelerate 3D graphics

[image]

What I would suggest is to install Windows 7 on your Mac using [BootCamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).